# How to change the value of a variable which is a value in a hash (using the hash)?

Tags: ruby, hashtable

I have a hashtable that I'm using to store variables as values. I want to be able to change those variables by looking them up in the hash, but I can't think of a way to do this without changing the value itself.

```
bar = "ruby"
foo = {key: bar}
foo
#=> { "key" => "ruby" }

foo[:key] = "rails"
foo
#=> { "key" => "rails" }
```

How do I alter a variable stored as a value in a hash, instead of altering the hash itself?

Comment: Variables are not objects so they cannot be stored as values. When you write `{ key: bar }`, where `bar` is a variable, the value of the key `:key` is set equal to the value of `bat` at the time. For example, if `bar = 'hi'; h = { key: bar } #=> { key: 'hi' }`, `h[:key]` no longer has anything to do with the value of `bar`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder why you would want to do such a thing, but you could store the names of the variables instead of the variables themselves:

```rb
bar = "ruby"
foo = {key: 'bar'}
```

Setting a variable:

```rb
eval("#{foo[:key]} = 'rails'")
p foo # {:key=>"bar"}
p bar # "rails"
```

Getting a variable:

```rb
eval(foo[:key])
```

Comment: I'm replacing a huge case statement that reassigns variables with this lookup that does the same. 3 lines instead of ~50. Thanks a lot, dude.

Comment: So does the above solve your use case then? Glad I could help

Comment: It does, brother.

Comment: solidstatejake, yes, this works, but its been been whupped to near death with an ugly stick. Under no circumstances should you do this in real code. (I do not fault Matthieu, and am sure he would agree. This is simply what you would have to do to achieve your objective,) I suggest you submit a question that presents your real problem (regarding the huge case statement) at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Its mandate is to suggest how working code can be improved. (SO, by contrast, deals with broken code and algorithmic issues.) You'll get some excellent answers at CR.